# Excel Pie-Chart in categories

Tags: excel, graph, charts, pie-chart

Basically the pie chart should display the data categorized by the category/color, showing each of the entries proportional to the value it has compared to the others. Data labels will have the name as well as the percentage. 
Sadly I could not get that to work in Excel as I wasn't able to categorize the different entries by their category/color.

Please see the pictures below to see what result I'm trying to achieve for the given data.

[[image: Data]

[[image: Chart to achieve]

Answer (score 0):

not an expert with graphs, but make a pivot pie chart. manually set the color of each category as you please. on the pivot table you can drag the order around to force them to be together if they are separate. this isn't the best way, but you can get by on it.

[image]